# Can we write condition in ON clause of left join which may or may not satisfy?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a table for audit trail which saves all actions performed records through out the project like add update and delete. 
there I maintain a column which saves primary keys of multiple tables on which action is performed. This is integer column

my query is like this

```
select * from 
user usr1  
left join activity_history 
on activity_history.userID= usr1.sequenceID

left join candidate can1 on can1.userID = usr1.sequenceID  
and can1.userID = activity_history.activity_sequenceID

left join institute ins1 on ins1.userID= usr1.sequenceID  
and ins1.userID = activity_history.activity_sequenceID

left join candidate_institutes caninst on caninst.candidateID = can1.candidateID and caninst.instituteID= ins1.instituteID

left join exam exam1 on exam1.instituteID = ins1.instituteID 
and exam1.examID = activity_history.activity_sequenceID

left join proctor pro1 on pro1.userID = usr1.sequenceID 
and pro1.proctorID = activity_history.activity_sequenceID

left join appointment appt1  on  appt1.examID = exam1.examID
  and appt1.sequenceID = activity_history.activity_sequenceID

/*  COMMENTED CODE-----

 on(  activity_history.activity_sequenceID=can1.userID
 OR activity_history.activity_sequenceID=ins1.userID
OR activity_history.activity_sequenceID=exam1.examID  and activity_history.userID= usr1.sequenceID
 OR activity_history.activity_sequenceID=pro1.userID
 OR activity_history.activity_sequenceID=appt1.sequenceID
  )
*/

order by activity_history.sequenceID desc
```

activity_sequenceID is the column where I am storing keys of other tables 
I need to map that. Is this a right way to join these tables or Commented part could be the rite way ?
Or is there any other way to join these tables. 
I am confused because I am writing a condition in but activity_histry table may or may not have records of that particular table .

Comment: Yes, the join condition can be false. Since it is an outer join, you will still get the rows from the right side and null for all columns from the missing left side.

Comment: Thanks  Thilo.  So both the ways are rite? Can I join activity_history table at last of other tables and write all the conditions using OR inside ON clause ?

Comment: No, you have to put the clauses to the proper joins, not shuffle them around. otherwise it will create something very weird.